# How to install memusg linux tool

Tags: linux, installation

I've tried with `yum install memusg` but returned:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
No package memusg available
Error: nothing to do
```

Any solution?

Comment: I suggest putting this to Super User or Unix & Linux (mention also which GNU/Linux distribution you're using and which software repositories you've enabled).

Answer (score 0):

The error seems that `memusg` tool not added in your software repository.

[check this github link](https://gist.github.com/netj/526585) for `memusg` script.

Comment: I am new in Linux, how can I run this script on my server?

Comment: you mean running this shell script in your server?